# rand string in C

Tags: c++, c

Задание такоe:

Написать генератор случайных слов от 3 до 5 букв (определить случайно). Используя правила:

- начинать слово с гласной или согласной
  (определить случайно);
- чередовать гласные и согласные буквы в слове.

Написал код, но появляются неожиданные результаты. При отладке переменная words принимает параметры больше 6. И символы выводятся неизвестные.

```
int main(void)
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int glasn[6] = { 97, 101, 105, 111, 117, 121 }; //Код англ гласных
    int sglasn[20] = { 98, 99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108,
                     109, 110, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 118, 119, 120,
                     122 };  //Код англ согласных
    int words = 4 + rand() % 6;  //Количество символов в строке
    char *randomS = (char*)malloc(words * sizeof(char)); //Массив символов
    randomS[0] = 97 + rand() % 122; //Определение первого символа

    for (int i = 1; i < words - 1; i++)
    {
        // Проверка на гласность предыдущего сивола
        if (randomS[i - 1] == 97)
            randomS[i] = sglasn[0 + rand() % 19];
        else if (randomS[i - 1] == 101)
            randomS[i] = sglasn[0 + rand() % 19];
        else if (randomS[i - 1] == 105)
            randomS[i] = sglasn[0 + rand() % 19];
        else if (randomS[i - 1] == 111)
            randomS[i] = sglasn[0 + rand() % 19];
        else if (randomS[i - 1] == 117)
            randomS[i] = sglasn[0 + rand() % 19];
        else if (randomS[i - 1] == 121)
            randomS[i] = sglasn[0 + rand() % 19];
        // Если предыдущий символ согласный
        else
            randomS[i] = glasn[0 + rand() % 5];
    }

    randomS[words - 1] = 0;
    printf("%s", randomS);
    free(randomS);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand() % 6` выдает значения от 0 до 5 (включительно). Поэтому, Ваша переменная words принимает значения от 4 до 9 (включительно).

Если нужно от 3 до 5 (включительно), то нужен такой код

```
rand()%3 + 3
```

А много другого кода можно сильно-сильно упростить.

И наверно здесь `randomS[0] = 97 + rand() % 122;` также ошибка.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить как работает функция rand(). На нескольких сайтах посмотрел и все по одной схеме: начальное значение + rand() % конечное число

Comment: @Афдей Петров: Либо вы что-то сами неправильно поняли, либо ваши "сайты" несут чушь. Приведенная вами схема имеет следующий смысл: `начальное значение + rand() % длина диапазона`. Делитель для `%` - не "конечное число", а именно "длина диапазона".

Comment: Ну например www.mir-koda.ru/full_leson.php?id=8

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @Афдей Петров: Да, по ссылке на сайте написан полнейший бред.